# What is an alternative for .select() of javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have following code to select an element (which will be created dynamically):

```
document.all['ele' + count].select()
```

Above code is perfectly working in Google Chrome but gives an error in all versions of Internet Explorer:

> SCRIPT16389: Incorrect function.

What could an alternative for `.select()` that can work in both Google Chrome and IE?

***Edit:***

I will have following `Textarea` for above function to select

```
<textarea name="ele[5][t]" id="ele5"></textarea>
```

Comment: Why on earth are you using `document.all`?

Comment: @DerFlatulator, Sorry but it's already there. That's why I asked an alternative. But people here just down voted this question.

Comment: You are probably best off using jQuery selector as `$('ele' + count)`

Comment: So (just to verify) this is an input element that you're trying to select?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy, Yes, it's a Textarea.

Comment: Although i agree with the advices, regarding the functions you are using.I tried your code and it seems to work fine for both chrome and ie8 http://jsbin.com/AGIBemO/2  , have a look please.

Comment: You might want to post a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can see what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select()` is probably not the problem. It's almost certainly the use of `document.all`.

Javascript solution:

```
document.getElementById("ele" + count).select();
```

jQuery solution:

```
$('#ele' + count)[0].select();
```

Both are equivalent.

**EDIT**

IE seems to have a bug regarding hidden inputs [(source)](https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5/issues/9), try using jQuery to get around it:

```
$('#ele' + count).select();
```

Or:

```
$('#ele' + count).focus();
```

Comment: I have also tried with `document.getElementById()` but still getting same error **SCRIPT16389: Incorrect function.**

Comment: As I told that if I use .select() of jQuery then it gives me Incorrect function error

Comment: Note the difference between `$('#ele' + count)[0].select();` and `$('#ele' + count).select();`. Also in your question's edit, should you be using `$('#t_newele' + count)` instead?

Comment: @NullPointer You don't have an `id` with value `ele5`, you've `t_newele5`, even the `document.all` stuff still works with the correct `id`...

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to bind a jQuery function to a regular javascript object?  Have you tried doing it this way instead?

```
$("#ele"+count).select();
```

?

Comment: Doesn't this just trigger the `select` event for that element?

Comment: I am getting error `jquery-1.7.1.min.js, line 3 character 3385`

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy, Can you please suggest some solution?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use document.getElementById? document.all is not longer supported as you can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537434%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Or even `document.querySelector` or `document.querySelectorAll`

Answer (score 0):

This is your element

```
<textarea name="newele[5][t]" id="t_newele5"></textarea>
```

To select it using `jQuery`, you may use

```
$('#t_newele5').action(...); // selects the element ussing it's "id"
```

Here `action` is `pseudo` command to denonstrate the process of calling a method on an element. For example, to call `css()` method on selected `textarea` you can write this

```
$('#t_newele5').css('color', 'red');
```

Remember to keep your `jQuery` code inside `ready` event handler, like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#t_newele5').css('color', 'red');
    // more code
});
```

[An Example Here.](http://jsbin.com/URUFuzE/1/edit)

Using vanilla `JavaScript` you can do it like

```
document.getElementById('t_newele5').style.color = 'green';
```

[An Example Here.](http://jsbin.com/URUFuzE/2/edit)